# Bypass the matrix inversion in the quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the vector $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and matrix $\boldsymbol{\Phi} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$, how to reformulate the expression
$$
\mathbf{v}^{\top}(\boldsymbol{\Phi}\boldsymbol{\Phi}^{\top} + \lambda \boldsymbol{I})^{-1}\mathbf{v}
$$
in such a way, that it is necessary to invert matrix $d \times d$ instead of $n \times n$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbf \Phi = \begin{bmatrix}& \\ 
\mathbf \phi_1 & \mathbf \phi_2 & \cdots & \mathbf \phi_d\\
&\end{bmatrix}$ and $\mathbf S_0 = \frac{1}\lambda \mathbf I = \left(\lambda \mathbf I\right)^{-1}$ and for $1\le l \le d$,

\begin{align}
\mathbf S_{l} &= \mathbf S_{l-1} - \frac{\psi_l \psi_l^\top}{1 + \phi_l^\top \psi_l}
\end{align}

where $\psi_l = \mathbf S_{l-1}\phi_l$. At the end of this procedure the $\mathbf S_d = \left(\mathbf \Phi\mathbf \Phi^\top + \lambda \mathbf I\right)^{-1}$. I am not sure if this will help you but I put it here anyway.

Comment: Thanks! It is some kind of iterative approach (by the way what is the name of the algorithm?). But I'm need something non-iterative. Like Woodbury identity.